# UI-Router: create rules to prevent access to a state

Tags: angularjs, url-routing, single-page-application, angular-ui-router

In [UI-router FAQ](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-create-rules-to-prevent-access-to-a-state), they suggested some way for preventing access to some states based on `data.rule` method of states. Assuming current user is determined by some `$currentUser` service.

However this assumption doesn't seem to be true in real world use cases. Because normally this `$currentUser` service is implemented in a way that it queries current user from the server and probably the best it can return is a **`promise`** of the current user. Therefore, at the moment that `$stateChangeStart` event is triggered, it's quite possible for this promise to not be resolved yet.

So what's the best thing to do, considering the above discussion?

### NOTE:

One workaround might be to include a `resolve` property in every secured state, with a function that returns the promise of the current user. But I really don't like it because it kinda breaks encapsulation in my mind.

Comment: Indeed, its a very common requirement to have an app wait for data to be fetched from server before it even starts and determine a state. 

We use 'resolve' in an 'upper' abstract state that is always being used. It should be noted that in case of nested states *all* resolves needs to be resolved before the app instantiates the controller etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution here would be to **postpone UI-Router execution** - until `$currentUser` is resolved. The technique could profit from built in feature: **`deferIntercept(defer)`**

#### [$urlRouterProvider](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider)

> The `deferIntercept(defer)`
>
> Disables (or enables) deferring location change interception.
>
> If you wish to customize the behavior of syncing the URL (for example, if you wish to defer a transition but maintain the current URL), call this method at configuration time. Then, at run time, call $urlRouter.listen() after you have configured your own $locationChangeSuccess event handler.

All the details could be found and observed here

- [AngularJS - UI-router - How to configure dynamic views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29013914/1679310)